# Avoid lag when scaling image

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scale

I have this problem, my image is very lagy when i'm scaling it using the `transform: scale();` property in CSS. I'm scaling the picture from 0 to 1.

My picture is downsize by a lot so I don't think the problem could come from here.

Here's a video of the actual problem : [lag image video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbXI-aePveI)

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="picture-container first-part">
          <div
            class="picture-frame first-part"
            :style="{
              width: pictureFrameWidth + '%',
              height: pictureFrameHeight + 'vh',
            }"
          >
            <img
              src="../assets/pictures/cathedrale.jpg"
              alt="picture of Notre Dame de Reims"
              class="picture top-left"
              id="firstPic"
              :style="{ transform: 'scale(' + pictureScale + ')' }"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.picture-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-self: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.picture-container.first-part {
  position: sticky;

  top: 0px;
}
.picture-frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  padding: 5%;

  border: solid 1px var(--color);
}
.picture {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS :

```
constrain(n, high, low) {
      return Math.max(Math.min(n, high), low);
    },
resizePicture() {
  this.pictureScale = window.scrollY / 1500 - 0.75;
      let constrainedPictureScale = this.constrain(this.pictureScale, 1, 0);
      this.pictureScale = constrainedPictureScale;
}
```

I'm calling the `resizePicture()` function when the user scroll.

So if you have any idea of how I could optimize this or do it in a different way, I just don't want this lag.

Comment: Have you tried all the usual turn it on and off again stuff? Browser cache, different browsers, other machines, opening the file directly instead of using live preview? I tried your code using a random image and no matter how aggressively I scale or scroll the window it doesn't lag, so I'm not sure it's a code-specific issue. What size is the image itself? If you have Photoshop, you could use the save for web function to reduce it

Comment: So I just try with another machine and it worked well but my pictures are taking forever to load. The size of the image is 3818 x 2546 and is 11.6 Mo, wich suppose is huge for a website but I have no idea on how to optimize it because I don't have Photoshop unfortunetly

Comment: Yeah for a website that's huge and it doesn't need to be either. You have to remember that a lot of users are on 2k monitors and some are on even smaller, not to mention mobile devices and so on, so very few people are going to get to appreciate an image of that size anyway. I just tried https://www.reduceimages.com/ and it was quick and the end result was very close to the original so I'd give it a shot.  That's probably the easiest option for you if you're not into Photoshop or an equivalent. For reference, my original image was 4mb and I got it down to 0.2mb with very little quality loss.